# Drupal inserts a different datetime field depending on the user who inserts the data

Tags: datetime, drupal

I have drupal 9.2.10

I created a type of "event" content.

I added a type of "datetime" field "startdate".

I created two different users "Elena" and "Gloria".

I created a role and assigned it to users "Elena" and "Gloria".

Elena inserts an event on 21/03/2023 10:00:00 and startdate in Frontend is viewed 21/03/2023 10:00:00

Gloria inserts an event on 21/03/2023 10:00:00 and startdate in Frontend is viewed 21/03/2023 09:00:00

How is it possible? What can it depend on?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a what can I do to fix this programming problem question but I can give you hints:
You are on a MET timezone and 03/21/2023 10:00:00 is inserted as GMT. 21/03/2023 ist also a European Date which adds to my guess.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong, the problem is only the time